# Cannot start application in android studio emulator since 2.0 update

Tags: android, android-studio-2.0

I recently (2 days ago) updated my Android Studio to version 2.0.

After having troubles with my previously working application on a real device, I had to activate MultiDex to remove errors in the logcat...

All is working fine now, as it was before the update.

But when I try to launch my application in the emulator from Android Studio (which was working before the update) I face a strange error without any explanation (this is from the Android Studio "4: Run" tab):

```
04/13 13:20:40: Launching app
No apk changes detected since last installation, skipping installation of /.../app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk
$ adb shell am force-stop com.android.test
$ adb shell am start -n "com.android.test/com.android.test.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Unexpected error while executing: am start -n "com.android.test/com.android.test.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Error while Launching activity
```

(I replaced the entire location by `/.../` in the above lines as this is not relevant to the problem...)

The strange fact is the application works perfectly well on the AVD if launched manually (by clicking on the application icon on the virtual device)!

Now if you guys have an idea of what is happening and how to get rid of it, it would be nice.

PS: I tried removing the MultiDex, nothing changed, facing same issue...

Comment: I faced a similar issue. I deleted my old emulator and created a new one and it worked (install latest build tools first from sdk manager)

Comment: 2.0 instant run is very buggy . If you want to use it you have to update to 2.1. It is bit stable in this version

Comment: Instant run is deactivated as it cannot be used with MultiDex applications... So I don't know if it's the problem here? I will try to delete/recreate my emulator as suggested.

Comment: Deleting/recreating the AVD does not change anything unfortunately...

Answer (score 2):

The new "instant run" feature is a bit buggy still, delete the app manually on your virtual device and run the code again.

Comment: no need to delete app. You can stop the current process and then run it again

Comment: Not always, some wrong dex files stay on the device and cause exceptions when running it again, at least this has been my experience these last few days on 2.0

Comment: 2.0 is very buggy. My instant run never worked properly but is lot better in 2.1 version

Comment: I deleted/recreated the AVD, so the app was not present on the AVD but when I tried to run the app from Android Studio, it produced the same error as my OP... So I guess deleting the app will not help. I'll try the 2.1 version of Android Studio as @VivekMishra suggested...

Comment: @Slander 2.1 is available in canary channel so you have to change from beta to canary to have 2.1

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for write on outdated post , but i had same problem. I was using AVD with arm processor image and received this same message.
The only way for me to make Android Studio 2.1.2 runs the app with instant run was change to a X86 processor image.